# Nested inner class access to outer class

Tags: c++, inner-classes, default-constructor

- I have a **nested class** that needs to **manipulate the data members of its outer class**.
- I demand that the outer class will **not** have an empty constructor.
- The following version compiles fine
- Is there any way to avoid using `Outer *o` inside `Inner`, and use `Outer o`?

```
class Outer {
private:
    class Inner {
    private: Outer *o;
    public:
        Inner(Outer *outer):o(outer){}
        void visit() { o->d=65; }
    };
private:
    int d;
    Inner v;
public:
    Outer(int m):d(m),v(this){}
};

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    Outer out(16);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Yes, why can't you just remove the *? Then change v(this) to v(*this) and -> to .

Comment: @OmidCompSCI it doesn't compile

Comment: No, it will become cyclic.

Comment: Not recommended by any stretch, but technically in the Inner scope `o == (Outer *)((char *)this - offsetof(Outer, v))` for POD types.

Comment: Just in passing, some languages (I'm looking at you, Java) give a technical meaning to "inner class". In C++ it's just a nested class, and the term "inner class" suggests things that aren't the case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, if you create a new instance, the situation will become cyclic. Instead of using pointer to the outer class, you can however use a reference, like so:

```
class Outer {
private:
    class Inner{
    private:
        Outer& o;
    public:
        Inner(Outer& outer) :o(outer) {}
        void visit() { o.d = 65; }
    };
private:
    int d;
    Inner v;
public:
    Outer(int m) :d(m), v(*this) {}
};

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    Outer out(16);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If we assume:

- class A has a member variable `class B b;`
- class B has a member variable `class A a;`

Then the size of `A` and `B` is infinite.